# Элементы видны за пределами Grid в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, overflow

У меня есть Grid в котором находяться другие Grid которые, в свою очередь содержат в себе по картинке и надписи. Задумка в том чтобы когда увеличиваеться ширина основного Grid, надписи и названия должны появиться так-как они войду в видимую часть Grid'a. Как вы поняли, этого не происходит...

---

[image: Собственно проблема]

---

**КОД:**

```xml
<Grid x:Name="Menu_panel" Background="#FF1D1C22" MouseEnter="Open_menu" MouseLeave="Close_menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="531"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="66"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle x:Uid="Right_menu" Fill="#FF24232B" Height="48" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="128" Margin="0,0,-62,0"/>
    <Label x:Uid="Right_menu" x:Name="Username_field" Content="Username" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="81" FontFamily="Century Gothic" Foreground="#FFE2E2E2" Margin="43,1,-58,504" FontSize="14"/>
    <Rectangle x:Uid="Right_menu" Fill="#FF34323E" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="7,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="34" StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
    <Ellipse x:Uid="Right_menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="7" Margin="107,36,-48,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="7" Stroke="#FF2A2932" StrokeThickness="0.5">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="1,1">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF96FF18" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF59FF0C" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
    <Image Margin="8,8,0,0" Source="User_icon.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="32"/>
    <Label x:Uid="Right_menu" Content="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="43,23,-41,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" FontFamily="Century Gothic" Foreground="#FFE2E2E2" Height="25"/>
    <Grid x:Name="Downloads_Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43" MouseEnter="Downloads_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Downloads_MouseLeave" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" Background="#001D1C22" Margin="0,48,-63,0">
        <Rectangle x:Name="Dowloads_BG" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" Focusable="False" Opacity="0">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF212027"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Image Focusable="False" Margin="11,7,0,9" Source="IconArtboard 19BIGGER.png" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="27"/>
        <Label x:Uid="Right_menu" Focusable="False" Content="Downloads" Foreground="#FFE2E2E2" FontFamily="Century Gothic" Margin="43,11,10,9"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="ModPacks_Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MouseEnter="ModPacks_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="ModPacks_MouseLeave" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128" Background="#001D1C22" Margin="0,96,-62,0" Height="48">
        <Rectangle x:Name="ModPacks_BG" Focusable="False" Opacity="0" Height="48" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF212027"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Label x:Uid="Right_menu" Focusable="False" Content="Modpacks" Margin="46,13,10,10" Foreground="#FFE2E2E2" FontFamily="Century Gothic"/>
        <Image Focusable="False" Margin="10,10,0,10" Source="Collection.png" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="28"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="Settings_panel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="128" Margin="0,483,-62,0">
        <Image Margin="9,0,0,9" Source="Settings_icon.png" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="31" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <Label x:Uid="Right_menu" Content="Settings" Margin="51,0,0,10" Foreground="#FFE2E2E2" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Century Gothic" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Если вы будете позиционировать ваши элементы с помощью отступов, то так все и будет. Научитесь пользоваться контейнерами, а отступы задавать только тогда когда это необходимо на самом деле.

Comment: Обрезка содержимого в WPF, это `ClipToBounds="True"`. Установите его к нужному блоку (например к `Grid x:Name="Menu_panel"`) и получите нужный результат.

Comment: Во первых, это нужная ситуация, во вторых, уже нашел решение проблемы. В любом случае спасибо за помощь :D

Answer (score 1):

Как не странно, уже второй мой вопрос на данном форуме получет ответ от меня :D

---

В любом случае, проблема была в делениях... Оказываеться WPF определяет находиться ли объект за пределом Grid по тому, находиться ли он за пределами делений. Странно и запутанно, но как-то так...

---

**Решение**

 Удалить или сдвинуть максимально в право RowDefinition.